# Шкала для QGraphicsScene

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsscene

Вопрос у меня следующий - у меня есть QGraphicsScene и Qpixmaр(который является изображением водопада сигнала) на ней. Я хочу добавить под и справа от QPixmapa шкалы частоты и времени на свободном пространстве сцены. Непосредственно вопрос - есть ли для этого готовые шаблоны у Qt или все самому ручками?

Comment: По всей видимости, вы ищете вот это https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtcharts-examples.html

Comment: или вот это https://www.qcustomplot.com/

Comment: Alexandr Chernin, да возможно из этого получится собрать нужное решение, благодарю.